# Generate notification subscriptions in external LOB?

Tags: remote-event-receiver

Looking at the [External events and alerts in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164024.aspx) article, the flow for subscribing to notifications from an external LOB is as follows:

1. **User requests a subscription for notifications.** Using a custom user interface (a button on a page or a ribbon), SharePoint initiates a request to the external system app for notifications.
2. **SharePoint generates a delivery address.** As part of the Subscribe process, SharePoint creates a REST endpoint where notifications will be delivered.
3. **Subscription request is sent to the external system.** SharePoint then encapsulates the requestor information along with the dynamically generated REST URL, and sends a web request to the external system.
4. **External system receives request.** There are different possibilities for implementing a subscription store. In this example, you will use a SQL Server database table.
5. **External system generates a subscriptionId.** A new subscriptionId is generated using code in the line-of-business (LOB) application. The subscriptionId should be a GUID.
6. **External system records the subscription.** The external system application records the subscriptionId, delivery address, event type, and other information sent from SharePoint into the subscription store.
7. **External system sends the subscriptionId back to SharePoint.** For SharePoint to correctly route the updates that are sent by the external system, the subscriptionId is sent back to SharePoint and SharePoint records that information in its database.

Is it possible to alter the work-flow so that the subscription can be created in the external LOB by pressing a "Subscribe to events" button there, then making the correct calls to Sharepoint, as long as the endpoint is already set up there?